# How to handle illegal argument exception on a string->enum conversion?

Tags: java

Say I have this enum type:

```
public enum Type { VALUEA, VALUEB };
```

And want to switch from string to this enum, using valueOf(). 
How to handle this case, making it return a default value?

```
Type.valueOf("NOTVALID");
```

Comment: `want to switch from string to this enum`, please clarify more as to what you want?

Comment: I'd like for valueOf() to return a default value when the passed String object has no corresponding enum type

Answer (score 1):

```
public Type getMyEnum(String value){
    Type expectedType;
    try {  
         expectedType = Type.valueOf(value);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
         expectedType = Type.YOUR_DEFUALT_ONE;
    }
    return expectedType;
}
```

Comment: But you should never ever use catching an excaption to control your program flow! It is an exception and it should be used like that!

Comment: Check this out: https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/java-enum-lookup-by-name-or-field-without-throwing-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As the enum value is retrieved for a String you have use the name() method.

```
  enum Type {
    VALUEA,
    VALUEB;

    public static Type valueOfOrDefault(String value) {

      for(Type type : getClass().getEnumConstants()) {
        if(type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
          return type;
        }
      }
      return Type.VALUEA;
    }

  }
```